# Iterating over image coordinates is only working when i change up x and y

Tags: java, loops, logic, bufferedimage

When iterating over my BufferedImage in Java, i would normally use a for loop like this:

`for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {`

For some reason this isnt working. However, when using a for loop like this:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
```

it works like a charm. I still use x and y like i would in the upper loop (bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y)) even though they are switched up. WHY?!

EDIT: I get width and height like this:

```
final int width = bufferedImage.getWidth();
final int height = bufferedImage.getHeight();
```

2nd EDIT: By not working i mean the rgb values are not matching with the actual ones. My picture only contains values like (0, 255, 0) / (255, 0, 0) / (0, 0, 255) and it tells me (255, 255, 255) and stuff like that. Also i get values even if it is transparent at that point.

3rd EDIT: For everyone having a similar problem:

-switching up x and y is not actually doing anything (in my case because i have a 12x12 image)

-colors like (255, 255, 255) appear when the image is transparent at that point. Idk why

Comment: Can you show from where you are populating the `width` and `height` variables?

Comment: How are you getting height and width? Check if you are assigning width from bufferedImage.getWidth() and height from buffImage.getHeight(). My guess is you've interchanged these.

Comment: Also, When you say it isn't working, What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Edited it Arun Gowda & jbx

Comment: Do you take into account that (0; 0) is the TOP LEFT corner of the image?

Comment: Yes i do Andrei Makarevich

Comment: so the point of this useless exercise is what?? you edited three times - so we are left to answer WHAT???

Answer (score -1):

The meaning of 'x' here is the line x in your image and 'y' is the column y in your image because you are manipulating pixels. So x goes from 0 to Height and y from 0 to Width.

Comment: there is no such issue with getRGB method

Comment: Yes it works but it doesnt give you the color but in a wrong way because you made x < width but it is < height not width . getRGB( the line of the pixel , the column of the pixel ) and you made the inverse it gives you a result but not the result you want because you inverted between x and y.